# SQL Query number of units in each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help with an SQL Server query to get below results.

An SQL query to report how many units in each category have been ordered on each day of the week

This is current syntax

```
SELECT TOP 3  ProductID , ProductQty  
FROM OrderDetails
ORDER BY  ProductQty DESC;
```

Here is the image from the database

[image: Products Table]

[image: Category Table]

[image: Orders Table]

[image: Order Details Table]

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

We can get your required result by dividing logic into two parts.

1. Firstly, get the product total count from order details
2. Secondly, we can assing category-wise rank to products with highest to lowest and pull the first 3 products from each category.

```
;WITH CTE_Data AS (
SELECT PD.PrdCategory AS PrdCategory, OD.ProductID AS ProductID, SUM(ProductQty) AS ProductQty
FROM OrderDetails OD (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN ProductDetails PD (NOLOCK) ON OD.ProductID = PD.PrdId
GROUP BY PD.PrdCategory, ProductID
)
, CTE_Data2 AS(
    SELECT PrdCategory, ProductID, ProductQty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PrdCategory, ProductID ORDER BY ProductQty DESC) AS RowNo
    FROM CTE_Data
)
SELECT ProductID, ProductQty
FROM CTE_Data2
WHERE RowNo IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the `NOLOCK` for, what locking problem were you trying to solve? `NOLOCK` is not a "go-faster" switch, it's a "give-incorrect-results" switch

Comment: No success with the query SELECT Products.PrdCategory AS PrdCategory, OrderDetails.ProductID, SUM(OrderDetails.ProductQty)
AS ProductQty
FROM OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.PrdId
GROUP BY Products.PrdCategory, Products.PrdId; Please suggest